# React state is always one step behind while making predictions on uploaded image using Tensorflowjs

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, react-redux, react-hooks, tensorflow.js

I'm developing a React app to classify Pokemon based on Images using Tensorflow.js.

- *What I want* - Upload an image of a Pokemon, generate predictions for the same Pokemon.
- *What is actually happening* - When I upload an image to make a prediction, the output is always for the previous image. So, 1st prediction is always garbage (random Pokemon). The predictions I get when I upload the 2nd Pokemon is always for the 1st Pokemon. 3rd Pokemon when uploaded gives prediction for the 2nd Pokemon and so on.

See the bottom of the question for a detailed version of where it works and where it doesn't.

Here are the relevant pieces of code -

1. I first check if the model is present in `indexeddb`, if yes, I load it into state `model`. If not, I fetch it from a server and store it in the state. This is what the first `useEffect` does upon the first render of the page.
2. I use another `useEffect` that runs whenever the `findState.uploadedImage` changes. This state is present in Redux-toolkit.

Here's a short demo of the problem => https://youtu.be/MX70zbupNWQ

Here's the app URL => https://poke-zoo.herokuapp.com/

Here's the Github repo => https://github.com/theairbend3r/poke-zoo/tree/master/frontend/src/features/find

Here's the file `SearchOutput.js`. This fetches the model and makes predictions.

```
const SearchOutput = () => {
  const findState = useSelector(selectorFind)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const imageRef = useRef(null)

  const [model, setModel] = useState(null)
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([])

  const MODEL_HTTP_URL = "api/pokeml/classify"
  const MODEL_INDEXEDDB_URL = "indexeddb://poke-model"

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchModel() {
      try {
        const localClassifierModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(
          MODEL_INDEXEDDB_URL
        )

        setModel(localClassifierModel)
        console.log("Model loaded from IndexedDB")
      } catch (e) {
        const classifierModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_HTTP_URL)
        setModel(classifierModel)

        await classifierModel.save(MODEL_INDEXEDDB_URL)

        console.error(e)
      }
    }
    fetchModel()
  }, [])

  const getTopKPred = (pred, k) => {
    const predIdx = []
    const predNames = []

    const topkPred = [...pred].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, k)

    topkPred.map(i => predIdx.push(pred.indexOf(i)))
    predIdx.map(i => predNames.push(idx2class[i]))

    return predNames
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function makePredictions() {
      if (imageRef && model) {
        try {
          const imgTensor = tf.browser
            .fromPixels(imageRef.current)
            .resizeNearestNeighbor([160, 160])
            .toFloat()
            .sub(127.5)
            .div(127.5)
            .expandDims()

          const y_pred = await model.predict(imgTensor).dataSync()
          const topkPredNames = getTopKPred(y_pred, 5)

          console.log(topkPredNames)
          return topkPredNames
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Unable to run predictions.")
        }
      }
    }
    makePredictions()
  }, [findState.uploadedImage])

  return (
     <div>
        {findState.uploadedImage && (
          <img
            ref={imageRef}
            tw="border border-purple-700 p-1 rounded shadow-lg"
            src={findState.uploadedImage}
            width={600}
            height={600}
          />
        )}


        <div>
           {findState.matchesFound.length === 6 &&
             findState.matchesFound.map(poke => (
               <PokemonCardML
                 key={`key-${poke.id}`}
                 pokemonId={poke.id}
                 pokemonName={poke.name}
                 pokemonType={poke.type}
                 pokemonHeight={poke.height}
                 pokemonWeight={poke.weight}
                 pokemonBaseExperience={poke.baseExperience}
                 pokemonSprite={poke.sprites}
               />
             ))}
       </div>
     </div>
)
}
```

Here's the file `findSlice.js` that stores the input image into the redux state.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import axios from "axios"

const initialState = {
  uploadedImage: "",
  model: null,
  matchesFound: [],
}

export const findSlice = createSlice({
  name: "find",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    storeInputImage: (state, action) => {
      state.uploadedImage = action.payload.uploadedImage
    },
    setModel: (state, action) => {
      state.model = action.payload.model
    },
  },
})

export const selectorFind = state => state.find
export const { storeInputImage, setModel } = findSlice.actions
export default findSlice.reducer
```

---

Details about the problem.

```
### Desktop

#### Table

|         |   Ubuntu    |     Windows      |      MacOS       |
| ------- | :---------: | :--------------: | :--------------: |
| Firefox | not working |   not working    |   not working    |
| Chrome  | not working | somewhat working | somewhat working |
| Safari  |     NA      |        NA        | somewhat working |

#### Comments

|         |                                    Ubuntu                                    |                                   Windows                                    |                                    MacOS                                     |
| :-----: | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------: | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------: | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------: |
| Firefox | Predictions are always one step behin for both Captured and Uploaded images. | Predictions are always one step behin for both Captured and Uploaded images. | Predictions are always one step behin for both Captured and Uploaded images. |
| Chrome  | Works only on Captured Images. Uploaded images give same predictions always. | Works only on Captured Images. Uploaded images give same predictions always. | Works only on Captured Images. Uploaded images give same predictions always. |
| Safari  |                                      NA                                      |                                      NA                                      | Works only on Captured Images. Uploaded images give same predictions always. |

### Mobile

#### Table

|         |     Android      |       iOS        |
| ------- | :--------------: | :--------------: |
| Firefox | somewhat working |   not working    |
| Chrome  | somewhat working |   not working    |
| Safari  |        NA        | somewhat working |

#### Comments

|         | Android                                                                     | iOS                                                                          |
| :-----: | --------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Firefox | No predictions load for a captured image. Works on uploaded images only.    | Camera does not load. Uploaded images give same predictions always.          |
| Chrome  | Works on capture images only. Uploaded images give same predictions always. | Camera does not load. Uploaded images give same predictions always.          |
| Safari  | NA                                                                          | Works only on Captured Images. Uploaded images give same predictions always. |
```

---

Edit: Based on the suggestions below. This has not solved the problem tho. Putting it here for reference.

```
const SearchOutput = () => {
  const findState = useSelector(selectorFind)
  const [imageRef, setImageRef] = useState(null)

  const onChangeRef = useCallback(node => {
    setImageRef(node)
  }, [])

  const [model, setModel] = useState(null)
  const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([])

  const MODEL_HTTP_URL = "api/pokeml/classify"
  const MODEL_INDEXEDDB_URL = "indexeddb://poke-model"


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchModel() {
      try {
        const localClassifierModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(
          MODEL_INDEXEDDB_URL
        )

        setModel(localClassifierModel)
        console.log("Model loaded from IndexedDB")
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          const classifierModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_HTTP_URL)
          setModel(classifierModel)

          await classifierModel.save(MODEL_INDEXEDDB_URL)
          console.log("Model saved to IndexedDB")
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Unable to load model at all: ", e)
        }
      }
    }
    fetchModel()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function makePredictions() {
      if (imageRef && model) {
        console.log(
          "Uploaded Image from inside the useEffect",
          findState.uploadedImage
        )
        console.log("ImageRef from inside the useEffect", imageRef.current)
        try {
          const imgTensor = tf.browser
            .fromPixels(imageRef.current)
            .resizeNearestNeighbor([160, 160])
            .toFloat()
            .sub(127)
            .div(127)
            .expandDims()

          const y_pred = await model.predict(imgTensor).data()
          console.log(y_pred)
          console.log(pokemonState)

          const topkPredNames = getTopKPredPokeObj(y_pred, 6, pokemonState)

          dispatch(storePredictions({ predictions: topkPredNames }))

          console.log(topkPredNames)

          return topkPredNames
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Unable to run predictions.", e)
        }
      }
    }
    makePredictions()
  }, [findState.uploadedImage])

  return (
    <div>
          {findState.uploadedImage && (
            <img
              ref={onChangeRef}
              src={findState.uploadedImage}
              width="600"
              height="600"
            />
          )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchOutput
```

Answer (score 1):

I've read about this issue before and I haven't encountered this myself but this should help you.

> The useRef hook can be a trap for your custom hook, if you combine it
> with a useEffect that skips rendering. Your first instinct will be to
> add ref.current to the second argument of useEffect, so it will update
> once the ref changes. But the ref isn’t updated till after your
> component has rendered — meaning, any useEffect that skips rendering,
> won’t see any changes to the ref before the next render pass.

As you can see on the behavior that you are encountering, the `imageRef.current` inside your `useEffect` is not returning the updated object which it is logging the previous value.

A logical way to this problem is to do something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function makePredictions() {
      //...
    }
    makePredictions()
  }, [findState.uploadedImage, imageRef.current])
```

But the problem with this is that changes in `imageRef.current` doesn't trigger a render in React. So based on React documentation on how to measure a DOM node, you should use `useCallback` instead of `useRef`.

Something like this should work:

```
  const [imageRef, setImageRef] = useState(null);
  const onChangeRef = useCallback(node => {
    // ref value changed to node
    setImageRef(node); // e.g. change ref state to trigger re-render
    if (node === null) { 
      // node is null, if DOM node of ref had been unmounted before
    } else {
      // ref value exists
    }
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function makePredictions() {
      if (imageRef && model) {
        try {
          const imgTensor = tf.browser
            .fromPixels(imageRef)
            .resizeNearestNeighbor([160, 160])
            .toFloat()
            .sub(127.5)
            .div(127.5)
            .expandDims()

          const y_pred = await model.predict(imgTensor).dataSync()
          const topkPredNames = getTopKPred(y_pred, 5)

          console.log(topkPredNames)
          return topkPredNames
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Unable to run predictions.")
        }
      }
    }
    makePredictions()
  }, [findState.uploadedImage, imageRef])
```

Instead of `<img ref={imageRef} />`, you should use `<img ref={onChangeRef} />`.

**References:**

[Ref objects inside useEffect Hooks](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780)

[How can I measure a DOM node?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)

Comment: What will come inside the if-else condition at the top? I tried the changes you suggested but that keeps the imageRef to null.

Comment: @theairbend3r nothing should be placed there, you could remove that. I noticed a typo where I used `<image>` instead of `<img>`, change that and see if it resolves your issue. I tested the method just now and it works for me. Key thing to note is that `findState.uploadedImage` should be something that changes after an upload. In my case, I used the string that is used on the img src. Reason for this is that the ref doesn't change when you replace the src for the img preview so you need to inform `useEffect` that things have changed.

Comment: I still get the error => `Error: "pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() can not be null"`. This error is because `imageRef` state is null I think. I have edited my post and added the new code you suggested. It also contains the place where I read the image using ref. Please take a look.

Comment: Also, `findState.uploadedImage` changes on image upload. It looks like this => `uploadedImage(pin): "blob:http://localhost:3000/80c0a810-7c86-4ed1-a78a-824e5d294610"`

Comment: @theairbend3r Your `findState.uploadedImage` is correct. On `.fromPixels(imageRef)` make sure you don't use `imageRef.current` since we changed to `useCallback`. Also, you already have an `if (imageRef && model)` so a null value should not happen.

Comment: If you `console.log(imageRef)` you should get something like this: `<img src="blob:http://localhost:3000/3dbc9155-8d6d-4152-94cc-0d133f862767" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216629/discussion-between-theairbend3r-and-jegtugado).

Answer (score 1):

On first sight it looks like the cause could be the missing dependency of "model" in the useEffect that holds the makePredictions function. Since you are using model, and the effect is only triggered when findState.uploadedImage is updated. imageRef is a reference and therefore it doesnt have to be a dependency. "model" has to be since its a chaning state thorughout your flow.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function makePredictions() {
      if (imageRef && model) {
        try {
          const imgTensor = tf.browser
            .fromPixels(imageRef)
            .resizeNearestNeighbor([160, 160])
            .toFloat()
            .sub(127.5)
            .div(127.5)
            .expandDims()

          const y_pred = await model.predict(imgTensor).data()
          const topkPredNames = getTopKPred(y_pred, 5)

          console.log(topkPredNames)
          return topkPredNames
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Unable to run predictions.", e)
        }
      }
    }
    makePredictions()
  }, [findState.uploadedImage, model]) // added model and remove imageRef
```

I hope that helps. I didnt fully try to understand exactly whats going on but that caught my eye and usually causes such errors.

Comment: I tried that. Does not work. Predictions are still one step behind.